# Error while displaying Summernote content from mongodb in meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, summernote

I'm making simple blog application and I'm getting the error while I load from db

Template

```
<template name="view">
 <div>
         {{{ summernote }}}
 </div>
</template>
```

Displaying from Mongodb.....

```
  <div class="container">
{{> editor}}

  {{#each post }} {{> view}} {{/each}}
```

main.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.body.helpers({

    post: function () {

      return Post.find();
    }
  });

  Template.editor.onRendered(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#summernote').summernote({

        height: 300
      });
    });
  });

  Template.editor.events({
    'click #saveContent': function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      var summernote = $('#summernote').summernote('code');

      Meteor.call('posts.insert', summernote);
    }
  });
}
```

lib.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Post = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

Meteor.methods({

  'posts.insert'(summernote) {

    check(summernote, String);
    Post.insert({
      summernote,
      createdAt: new Date()
    });
    console.log(summernote);
  }
});
```

And I'm getting following errors

Exception in queued task: Spacebars.include@http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?hash=547cf8e466d1d52603d19bd5f48fb5df184fd237:48:13
    template.main.js/http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=47d4ac698c02f59520602a8871b3d5485a3a5b26:31:19
    doRender@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:2086:20
    viewAutorun/http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:1934:18
    Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:3744:12
    viewAutorun/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:1932:14
    Blaze._withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:2271:12
    viewAutorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:1931:12
    Tracker.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=0e8b5c18d543a28ce43b2f183c26b49ee62196af:339:5
    Tracker.Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=0e8b5c18d543a28ce43b2f183c26b49ee62196af:229:5
    Tracker.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=0e8b5c18d543a28ce43b2f183c26b49ee62196af:613:11
    Blaze.View.prototype.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:1944:14
    Blaze._materializeView/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:2080:5
    Tracker.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=0e8b5c18d543a28ce43b2f183c26b49ee62196af:640:12
    Blaze._materializeView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:2079:3
    addedAt/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:2851:25
    Tracker.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=0e8b5c18d543a28ce43b2f183c26b49ee62196af:640:12
    addedAt@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:2824:9
    addedAt@http://localhost:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?hash=5da2e60ce61e074a6463979f3992dd5bac41b43d:373:9
    addedBefore@http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?hash=9d4bb4b714acae5bd3d70f96bb3803e155b57e38:3372:11
    addedBefore@http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?hash=9d4bb4b714acae5bd3d70f96bb3803e155b57e38:2836:13
    wrapCallback/http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?hash=9d4bb4b714acae5bd3d70f96bb3803e155b57e38:1827:13
    SQp.runTask@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=c9a34f92f28ede5a42eac467d3fa1763b624436a:782:9
    SQp.flush@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=c9a34f92f28ede5a42eac467d3fa1763b624436a:811:3
    SQp.drain@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=c9a34f92f28ede5a42eac467d3fa1763b624436a:820:5
    resumeObservers@http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?hash=9d4bb4b714acae5bd3d70f96bb3803e155b57e38:2438:7
    endUpdate@http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo.js?hash=7dae0d2bbf4992c92bbb005435b6ee27a23d13b2:339:9
    registerStore/http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=a547928b29e722e419948bbc25e954f2c268a1c3:631:20
    _performWrites/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=a547928b29e722e419948bbc25e954f2c268a1c3:1630:11
    _performWrites@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=a547928b29e722e419948bbc25e954f2c268a1c3:1629:9
    _flushBufferedWrites@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=a547928b29e722e419948bbc25e954f2c268a1c3:1587:7
    _livedata_data@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=a547928b29e722e419948bbc25e954f2c268a1c3:1548:9
    onMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=a547928b29e722e419948bbc25e954f2c268a1c3:2153:9
    _launchConnection/this.socket.onmessage/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/socket-stream-client.js?hash=55bf4fc2eb00d41c79827f8ec3b3949bbec01ce1:261:13
    forEachCallback@http://localhost:3000/packages/socket-stream-client.js?hash=55bf4fc2eb00d41c79827f8ec3b3949bbec01ce1:355:7
    _launchConnection/this.socket.onmessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/socket-stream-client.js?hash=55bf4fc2eb00d41c79827f8ec3b3949bbec01ce1:260:11
    sockjs-0.3.4.js/SockJShttp://localhost:3000/packages/socket-stream-client.js?hash=55bf4fc2eb00d41c79827f8ec3b3949bbec01ce1:645:7
    sockjs-0.3.4.js/SockJShttp://localhost:3000/packages/socket-stream-client.js?hash=55bf4fc2eb00d41c79827f8ec3b3949bbec01ce1:1824:5
    sockjs-0.3.4.js/SockJShttp://localhost:3000/packages/socket-stream-client.js?hash=55bf4fc2eb00d41c79827f8ec3b3949bbec01ce1:1890:11
    sockjs-0.3.4.js/SockJShttp://localhost:3000/packages/socket-stream-client.js?hash=55bf4fc2eb00d41c79827f8ec3b3949bbec01ce1:2048:7
    meteor.js:992:11

Comment: What's that `each` block doing outside of the `<template>` tag?

Comment: Where do you define 'summernote' ? Can you show it?

Comment: I have updated the code @MasterAM

Comment: @GokhanKaradag, which one {{{ summernote }}} ???

Comment: When you use triple brackets in Spacebar you should be careful because you are inserting a raw HTML within them.

Comment: What is the solution then.. Actually I read in few post why to use triple bracket...

Answer (score 0):

Try in your methods with

```
Post.insert({
      summernote: summernote,
      createdAt: new Date()
    });
```